# scss, same class, different elements html

Tags: sass

I use scss,

I have a css class, I need some css property to be different, depending of the html element:

```
<a class="myClass">...</a><input class="myClass"/>
```

I've try, but it don't work:

```
.myClass {
  &.someOtherClass{...} 
  &text-area{...}
  &input{...}
}
```

Any idea?

for easy readinf, I need the element to be define INSIDE the class, I can't use something like

```
input{ &.myClass{...}}
text-area{ &.myClass{...}}
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "balise"?

Comment: @NicoHaase

Sorry, by balise, I mean element (input, p, div...)

Answer (score 0):

With the `@at-root` directive you can write your SCSS code in a nested fashion but the resulting CSS will not be nested.

```
.myClass {
  @at-root input#{&} { color: red; }
}
```

will result in

```
input.myClass {
  color: red;
}
```

But honestly I don't find this better readable than just doing it KISS:

```
.myClass { ... }
input.myClass { ... }
```